# Angular get each tr data matching two td's

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple data table. Data feeds from two different services, however i need to match them and then sending back to server (in this case it's not important).

For example ( **Business** could match with blue or red -- **Home** could match with red or blue ). I think `angular.forEach` possible answer, however, i am new to angular.

**Desired output Json**

```
{ // result of first tr
  "PickOptionBaseID": 1, // first td from pickoptions (Business)
  "PickOptionTargetID": 20 // second td from pickoptionsTwo (Red)
},
{ //result of second tr
  "PickOptionBaseID": 2, // first td pickoptions (Home)
  "PickOptionTargetID": 10 //sencond td from pickoptionsTwo (Blue)
}
```

[Quick demo on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AXBut/138/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you want to send the select value back to the server?

Comment: Text and selected value to the server including two tr's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the second option to a property on the first (also use `ng-options`):

```
<select data-ng-model="p.optionTwo" ng-options="po.Text for po in pickoptionsTwo">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

Then construct the request data:

```
$scope.send = function() {
  var data = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.pickoptions, function (option) {
      data.push({
          PickOptionBaseID: option.ID,
          PickOptionTargetID: (option.optionTwo && option.optionTwo.ID) || 0
      });
  });

  console.log(data);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AXBut/141/

Comment: Getting error "Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined" after clicking on Send.

Comment: @camden_kid exactly. That could be another option. If the user don't want to be match right now (Could match later. i.e. Home it has to be stay as default (Choose ID : 0 ) )

Comment: Added check if optionTwo is set, otherwise 0

Comment: @agriboz Glad you finally got a solution. :-)